# Need C# Regex to match a four digit sequence, but ignore any single digits peceeding

Tags: c#, regex

OK, I need to improve this question. Let me try this again:

I need to parse out a flight time which comes after an airport code, but may have a single digit and white space between the two.

Example data:

```
ORD  1100
HOU 1 1215
MAD   4  1300
```

I tried this:

```
([A-Z]{3})\s?\d?\s?(\d{4})
```

I end up with the airport code and a single digit.
I need a regex that will ignore everything after the airport code except the 4 digit flight time.

Hope I improved my question.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? For future reference, it's always good to either mark the correct answer as Accepted, or write and accept the correct answer yourself.

Comment: Is this within the context of a much larger body of text? - your examples make it seem like the entire string is e.g. "ORD 1100" - in which case the answer seems to be to just take the rightmost 4 characters of each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I would use:

```
@"([A-Z]{3})\s+(?:[0-9]\s+)?([0-9]{4})"
```

Basically it is very similar to what you were attempting to do.

The first part is `([A-Z]{3})`, which looks for 3 uppercase letters and assigns them to group 1 (Group 0 is the entire string).

The second part is `\s+(?:[0-9]\s+)?`, which requires at least one space, with the possibility of 1 digit in there somewhere. The noncapturing group in the middle requires that if there is a single digit there, it must be followed by at least 1 space. This prevents a mismatch for something like `ABC 12345`.

Next we have `([0-9]{4})`, which simply matched the 4 digits you are looking for. These can be found in group 2. I use [0-9] here since `\d` refers to more digits than what we are used to (Like Eastern Arabic numerals).

Comment: I was with you right up until that last sentence.  If the targets are standalone strings (the OP hasn't really said yet), your regex will fail to match well-formed inputs because it expects the flight number to consist of five characters: four digits and one non-digit.  The correct way to say "can't be followed by a digit" is with a negative lookahead, e.g. `(?!\d)`.

Comment: But aside from the not-a-digit issue, this looks like the best answer to me.

Comment: Glad to hear it. @AlanMoore Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

The solution might be as simple as:

```
\d{4}
```

According to your inputs you don't need to care about *preceeding digits*..

Comment: Looks that way... beat me because I got a too short error. Good filler! +1

Comment: Not necessarily. It will also match sequences like "4339232".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little something, using *lookbehind* and *lookahead* to be sure there are only 4 digits, with non-digits (or beginning/end) surrounding them.

```
"(?<=[^\d]|^)\d{4}(?=[^\d]|$)"
```

The two `[^\d]` can be replaced with `[\s]` to only match 4-digits with whitespace around them.

**Update:**
With your latest update, I merged my regex with yours (from the comment) and came up with this:

```
"(?<=[A-Z]{3}\s(\d\s)?)\d{4}(?=\s|$)"
```

There are three parts to the pattern. First is the *lookbehind*: `(?<=PatternHere)`. The pattern inside this must occur/match *before* what we seek.

The next part is our simple main pattern: `\d{4}`, four digits.

The last part is the *lookahead*: `(?=PatternHere)`, which is pretty much the same as *lookbehind*, but checks the other side, *forward*.

Comment: I tried this expression, but no luck:  ([A-Z]{3})(?<=[^\s]|^)\d{4}(?=[^\s]|$)

Comment: Patrik, I need to capture both the carrier and the flight time. I tried the above regex with the "[A-Z]{3}" removed, like this: "(?<=\s(\d\s)?)\d{4}(?=\s|$)", but I haven't got it to work yet.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm kinda new to Regex, so I don't know how one would/can do that in a single match. On the other hand, you could first match the whole thing, then do a `regex.Replace("PatternToFindAnySingleDigit", string.Empty)` to remove the singles. I'm sorry I can't be of more help right now, but I'll try to answer it later if I've got the time.

Comment: This not a job for lookarounds.  Their purpose is to match parts of strings without consuming them, and we want to consume everything.  And if we were using them, *negative* lookarounds would be much more suitable: `@"(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)"`.  (Notice the `@` too.  In C# you should always use verbatim strings to write your regexes if you can.)

Comment: My regex being more specific was intentional though. Note this is from before I knew he wanted to consume more than the four digits.